# How to create a content Blocker in Android

Tags: android, flutter

I would like to know how to block the flow coming from a url in a browser from an android application.I cannot find documentation on this

Comment: You mean in Web View?

Comment: Please try to add some more details, research that you've done so far. Code block, article links would be better to help community find you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly: you can't.  This isn't a feature that Android provides an API for.

You could:

- Write an app that acts as a proxy and blocks content based on what goes through the proxy
- Write an extension for a browser with extension support, such as [Firefox](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/developing-extensions-for-firefox-for-android/) (but note that only [a small number of pre-approved extensions can be used outside of the Nightly version](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/find-and-install-add-ons-firefox-android))
- Create a filter list app for a browser that supports content blocking, such as [Samsung Internet](https://developer.samsung.com/internet/android/adblockers-guide.html).